# How can I set 'Calendar based room release' via google api

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

I am creating a room resource via the [Google Workspace Admin API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars). However there is no parameter to specify the `Calendar-based room release`. It is alway set to `Off` but I would like to have it set to `On`.

Is there anyway to do that with any Google API?

Comment: what actually is room release? is it also related to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755419/why-does-it-turn-into-an-unavailable-room-when-i-create-a-google-resource-calend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Currently, you can only turn room releases on or off via Admin console. This is not possible via Directory API in the current implementation.

#### File a feature request:

I'd suggest you to file a feature request in Issue Tracker (here is the [corresponding template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102)), if you think this functionality could be useful.

#### Update - Feature request filed:

- [Room release parameter for ressources can not be changed via Directory API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181577192)

#### Reference:

- [Free unused Google Calendar meeting rooms](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9047638?hl=en)
- [REST Resource: resources.calendars](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars)

Comment: what actually is room release? is it also related to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755419/why-does-it-turn-into-an-unavailable-room-when-i-create-a-google-resource-calend)?