# Why does it turn into an unavailable room when I create a google resource calendar with its API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

I'm going to create a google resource calendar room via its API (i.e. `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/resources/calendars`). But the problem is, when I create one, it turns into an unavailable (crossed out) room within google calendar rooms and I couldn't find any attribute to make it available!

Here's the body request/response:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#resources#calendars#CalendarResource",
  "etags": "\"CTyc505ppdmJR2motHVsU17kzItOkPo5vYViqlSF0rU/FB0b765ZgWIpTBaxn5YQIwZWWNM\"",
  "resourceId": "9f698cdc-84f9-4688-95a7-c2207b4fa7ae",
  "resourceName": "StackOverflow Test",
  "generatedResourceName": "Orangery Hildesheim Nordstadt-EG-StackOverflow Test (3)",
  "resourceEmail": "c_1881d77mmcaqsihgi426fseae6vnc@resource.calendar.google.com",
  "capacity": 3,
  "buildingId": "Orangery-Hildesheim-Nordstadt",
  "floorName": "EG",
  "resourceCategory": "CONFERENCE_ROOM"
}
```

Here's the output on google calendar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two months finally I found a solution!

In fact, the main problem is related to the lack of permission for those created resources for other users in the organization. To tackle this problem I used another google API named ACL (Access Control Level) <sup>[ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl)</sup>, to set a privilege for other users. Basically, a google resource actually is a google resource calendar, so you can use ACL API to access that calendar. Moreover, the parameter to reach that calendar is `resourceEmail` as the unique ID of the respective resource calendar.

Here's the thing I did to make unavailable resources to be available (bookable):

- ```
  POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl
  ```
- change `calendarId` with the value of `resourceEmail` of the google resource.
- the body of the request:

```
{
    "scope": {
        "type": "domain",
        "value": "orangery.io"  # if you selected type as `domain` you should write your domain name here.
    },
    "role": "writer"
}
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

With this procedure, you would need to the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` authorization scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is a solution to set the necessary permissions using Google Apps Script. By running this script, you should be able to set the necessary permissions for your Google resource calendars, which can potentially resolve the "unavailable room" issue.

Note: Before using this code, ensure that you've enabled the Google Calendar API in your Apps Script project and set up OAuth2 authentication. This is necessary for the script to have the required permissions to modify the calendar's ACL.

```
function setCalendarPermissions() {
  var domain = "domainName";
  var calendarIds = [
    "calendarId"
  ];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < calendarIds.length; i++) {
    var calendarId = calendarIds[i];
    addDomainPermission(calendarId, domain);
  }
}

function addDomainPermission(calendarId, domain) {
  var calendarService = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  if (calendarService) {
    var acl = {
      "role": "writer",
      "scope": {
        "type": "domain",
        "value": domain
      }
    };
    
    // Use Calendar API to add the ACL
    // Note: You will need to enable the Calendar API and set up OAuth2 authentication for this to work.
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + calendarId + "/acl";
    var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "payload": JSON.stringify(acl)
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  } else {
    Logger.log("Calendar with ID " + calendarId + " not found.");
  }
}
```

Please edit setCalendarPermissions() Function before execution and populate the following variables:

- domain: This variable should be set to your domain name (e.g.,
  "example.com").
- calendarIds: An array containing the IDs of the
  calendars you want to set permissions for. The function loops through
  each calendar ID and calls the addDomainPermission() function to set
  the permissions.

Comment: I think the essence of this answer — using ACL API with `role: writer`, is the same as my answer. BTW, I appreciate it.